# css/images not showing when hosting ASP.NET MVC in IIS on Vista Home Premium

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

my css and images are not showing when hosting ASP.NET MVC in IIS on Vista Home Premium.  Works fine when hosting through Visual Studio.  Pool is Integrated, static content is checked for IIS install, not sure what's going on.

I'm trying to hit my site from Virtual PC to test in IE6.  Prefereably I could test it from the host machine rather than the actual domain.  I can ping the virtual machine from the host machine and the host machine from the virtual machine but I can't reach the website from the host machine IP in a browser when hosted through Visual Studio.  Firewalls on VM and host are both disabled.

Any ideas on either why I can't hit the site in Visaul Studio from the Host.  I've trying enabling the loop back adaptor as well but can only get the VM to hit the internet with shared networking (NAT) enabled on the VM NIC.

Thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was this solved? I'm having the same problem in a shared hosting environment.
(IIS 7 integrated mode)

You can add static handlers for each file type in web.config to solve this problem, but that can't be the only solution.